# Finding text using ReSharper

Tags: c#, search, resharper

Resharper is a great tool, the only thing I seem to be missing is an easy text search option.
Searching online I have come across a few options (pattern search,key word search) , none of my found options were simple/quick searches.

I am looking something similar to "go to everything" [Ctrl+t or Ctrl+n]
[image]

only for text, as the above wont show parts of text.

example use case to clarify need - while coding I remember locations in code based on parts of string in code, for example I want to search for string "sanity check" I would like a list like the one above giving me the best results, making closer matches higher in the list.

thank you.

Comment: Why not just use the built in Visual Studio one? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then type in `sanity check` and it will list all places in the Solution that contains that?

Comment: @Belogix its a bit cumbersome, also results aren't set in order of priority, no coloring, does not have a neat 1 liner that fits in screen showing location+text+info.. and more. when jumping locations very quick the built in VS find is not comfortable. if it were like netbeans/intelij find it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [Go to Word](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-gotoword) Resharper Extension which allows you to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to search for text (only works in v8.X).

If you are using Resharper 2016.2 or later, this feature has been added to the core product. It works just as good as the original plugin.

Comment: +1 on Go to Word (created by one of ReSharper's developers!). Press Ctrl-T (or Ctrl-N) 3 times, and you can instantly find any word in any file.

Comment: Is there an easy install available for R# 9.0?

Comment: No longer supported in R#9. Plugin author indicated that it was done as a hack in 8.0 and v9.0 contains too many breaking changes. Apparently, it is in the potential roadmap for v9.X but release date given. It is too bad as I use this plugin quite a bit so I have stuck with v8.0 for now.

Comment: If `Ctrl-NNN` doesn't work, make sure that you have 'Go to Everything' enabled under ReSharper->Options->Environment->Search&Navigation->General.

Answer (score 3):

Adding as an answer too to help people in future:

Why not just use the built in Visual Studio one? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then type in `sanity check` and it will list all places in the Solution that contains that?

Comment: and click on find all rather than find. It displays all results in a list and its much faster

Comment: its a bit cumbersome, also results aren't set in order of priority,  no coloring, does not have a neat 1 liner that fits in screen showing location+text+info.. and more. when jumping locations very quick the built in VS find is not comfortable. if it were like netbeans/intelij find it would be acceptable.

Comment: It is actually useful in that you can go up and down the results, and the preview window will load the currently selected result, giving full context.